# Validation ASP.NET MVC Child Elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I'm building a screen with out-of-the-box validation. Allow me to clarify the situation using the following screenshot.

[image]

Above you see a collection of TemplateItems. The second column 'Uitvoerder' is required. This works fine in most cases.

The problem however, is that it's not a regular list of items, but that it's structured to represent the hierarchy shown in the UI. Hence the second item is a child of  the first, and thus contained in the first TemplateItem object you see.

Validation does not fire for the contained items.

You could argue that the front end model should be flattened and made less complex, but I'd like to avoid that. Is there any way I can have the validation trigger for the child elements as well?

The model looks like this:

```
public class WorkflowTemplateItemModel
    : IValidatableObject
{                
   public WorkflowTemplateItemModel[] ChildWorkflowTemplateItems { get; set; }

   public long? ExecutionParticipantId { get; set; }    

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
   {          
      if (ExecutionParticipantId == null)
      {
          yield return new ValidationResult("Contact needs to be specified",new[] {"ExecutionParticipantId"});
      }
   }
}
```

The relevant Razor part:

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExecutionParticipantId,
        Model.AvailableUsers.Select(user => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = user.UserName,
            Value = user.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = (Model.ExecutionParticipantId == user.Id)
        }),
        string.Empty
    )
</td>
```

and the razor which builds the tree view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ChildWorkflowTemplateItems.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ChildWorkflowTemplateItems[i], new { Depth = Depth +     1, ParentId = Model.WorkflowItemId, RootModel = GetViewData<CreateWorkflowModel>    ("RootModel") })
}
```

Comment: Need to see the code for ViewModel class/classes with attributes defined

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but you will need to create a custom validation including the client-side validation code.

The process is similar to this one: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx